# Alternative versions of Ubuntu for an old notebook

Tags: 10.10, system-requirements

I have an old notebook that has 512MB of RAM. I put Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook on it. It works, but I can't install any packages or a simple web browser. What alternative versions of Ubuntu do I have that are more compatible with my notebook?

Comment: An old notebook I have 512 mb of RAM you PUT Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Works POSSIBILITY But I do not how to install the package or des simple web browser . That alternative ( ubuntu version ) I have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On such a "low-end" device I'd recommend Lubuntu. Lubuntu is a lightweight version of Ubuntu, using the LXDE desktop environment.

It is specificly designed to work on machines with low amounts of RAM, old CPU's and small harddrives.

Download it from http://lubuntu.net/ , burn a CD/DVD with it, and try it out in the Live session.